# c# How do I take an int argument at the command line

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

I want to run my program at the command line using

```
dotnet program.dll --number 8
```

This is a section of my current code

```
else if (args[i] == "--number")
{
    if (0 > Convert.ToInt32(args[i+1]))
    {
        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(args[i + 1]);
    }
    else
    {
        num1 = 10; //default
        Console.WriteLine("The number value must be above 0. Returning to default value");
    }
}
```

However, since `args[]` is a `string[]`, the command line is stating that the argument `8` is *not accepted*. I was wondering how I can avoid this or use the `"--number"` input correctly to take int inputs after it is called

Comment: I suggest starting with a simpler program that just prints out each argument in order. Run this a few times with different argument values. That will help you understand how your program should behave in different scenarios.

Comment: you could make life easier for yourself... https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DragonFruitAndSystemCommandLineIsANewWayToThinkAboutNETConsoleApps.aspx / https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/march/net-parse-the-command-line-with-system-commandline

Comment: You could check the length of args, to make sure the right number of argumments is passed after `--number`, or you could use a 3rd party library, like [Command Line Parser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline)

Comment: The comparison operator should be > instead of <

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`; you have three possibilities to test:

1. Too few parameters: `dotnet program.dll --number`
2. Invalid number: `dotnet program.dll --number bla-bla-bla`
3. Nonpositive number: `dotnet program.dll --number 0`

Code:

```
else if (args[i] == "--number") {
  if (args.Length <= i + 1) {
    // dotnet program.dll --number 
    num1 = 10;

    Console.WriteLine("Too few parameters, no number found. Returning to default value");
  }
  else if (!int.TryParse(args[i + 1], out num1)) {
    // dotnet program.dll --number bla-bla-bla
    num1 = 10;
     
    Console.WriteLine("The number must be a positive integer. Returning to default value");   
  }

  if (num1 <= 0) {
    // dotnet program.dll --number 0
    num1 = 10;

    Console.WriteLine("The number value must be above 0. Returning to default value");   
  } 

  // from now on, num1 is a positive integer number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another common approach:

```
for(int i=0; i<args.Length; i++)
{
    if (args[i].StartsWith("--"))
    {
        switch (args[i].ToLower())
        {
            case "--number":
                if ((i + 1) < args.Length)
                {
                    int number;
                    string strNumber = args[i + 1];
                    if (int.TryParse(strNumber, out number))
                    {
                        if(number > 0)
                        {
                            // ... do something with "number" ...

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // number was not positive
                            Console.WriteLine($"--number Parameter ({args[i+1]}) was not positive!");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // parameter failed to convert to an integer
                        Console.WriteLine($"--number Parameter ({args[i+1]}) was not a valid Integer!");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // too few arguments - no parameter to go with command
                    Console.WriteLine("No parameter provided for --number command!");
                }
                break;

            case "--otherparameter":

                break;

            default:
                // unrecognized command was encountered
                Console.WriteLine($"Unrecognized command: {args[i]}");
                break;
        }
    }      
}
```